# Не удается каждый раз скачать/отрыть файл на VPS

Tags: apache, centos

На чистый сервер установил CENTOS 7, затем Аpache.

Все работает, но не так как полагается.

Если заливать изображения в www директорию и открывать их по протоколу Http. Работает на 101%.
Если загрузить файл к примеру видео, формат mp4(С остальными не смотрел). В таком случаи при открытии страницы, именно видеофайла. Страница может его отдать, то есть работает. Но в большинстве случаев страница просто долгое время грузит и все.
В итоге отдает

```
Не удаётся установить соединение с сайтом.
Соединение сброшено.
```

То есть если вечером залить видеофайл и он не будет открываться, то на утро откроется.

Не понимаю в чем тут может быть дело, по статистике все ресурсы загружены не более чем на 20%

Еще раз, сервер чистый, установил centos 7, затем Аpache. Из всех дефолтных настроек что изменил, так это путь до директории с 'var/www/html' на 'var/www/'. Сервер необходим только чтобы хранить и отдавать видеофайлы, не более.

В чем дело?

**Добавлено чуть позже**
В данный момент подгрузка файла зависла. Ввел команду top, посмотреть загрузку.
Вижу что последний процесс то появляется, то исчезает. Быть может в этом дело, как исправить/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://***.time4vps.cloud/video.mp4

Comment: Раза 3 удалось открыть файл, последующие разы зависает подгрузка. Аналогично с остальными файлами

Comment: начинать стоит как обычно: с анализа лог-файлов.